# login script not logging in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I can't wrap my head around oop just yet, so I'm sticking with procedural coding for now.

Ok, so the registration and auth portion of the scripts work, it's logging in that pitches a fit and I'm not sure where my error is.

```
<?php
include ('database_connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted']))
{
  // Initialize a session:
  session_start();
  $error = array();//this aaray will store all error messages
  if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) 
  {
    //if the email supplied is empty 
    $error[] = 'You forgot to enter  your Email ';
  } 
  else 
  {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) 
    {
      $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
    } 
    else 
    {
      $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
    }
  }
  if (empty($_POST['Password'])) 
  {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
  } 
  else 
  {
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
  }
  if (empty($error))//if the array is empty , it means no error found
  { 
    $query_check_credentials = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email ='$Email' AND cpassword='$Password') AND code IS NULL";
    $result_check_credentials = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_credentials);
    if(!$result_check_credentials)
    {
      //If the QUery Failed 
      echo 'Query Failed ';
    }
    if (@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1)
    //if Query is successfull A match was made.
    { 
      $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//Assign the result of this query to SESSION Global Variable
      header("Location: page.php");
    }
    else
    { 
      $msg_error= 'Either Your Account is inactive or Email address /Password is Incorrect';
    }
  }  
  else 
  {
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
    foreach ($error as $key => $values) 
    {
      echo '<li>'.$values.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol></div>';
  }
  if(isset($msg_error))
  {
    echo '<div class="warning">'.$msg_error.' </div>';
  }
  /// var_dump($error);
  mysqli_close($dbc);
} // End of the main Submit conditional.



?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login Form</title>





 <style type="text/css">
 body {
font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
 }
  .registration_form {
margin:0 auto;
width:500px;
padding:14px;
 }
 label {
width: 10em;
float: left;
margin-right: 0.5em;
display: block
 }
 .submit {
float:right;
 }
 fieldset {
background:#EBF4FB none repeat scroll 0 0;
border:2px solid #B7DDF2;
width: 500px;
 }
 legend {
color: #fff;
background: #80D3E2;
border: 1px solid #781351;
padding: 2px 6px
 }
 .elements {
padding:10px;
 }
p {
border-bottom:1px solid #B7DDF2;
color:#666666;
font-size:11px;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
a{
color:#0099FF;
font-weight:bold;
 }

/* Box Style */


.success, .warning, .errormsgbox, .validation {
border: 1px solid;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:10px 5px 10px 60px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px center;
 font-weight:bold;
 width:450px;

 }

 .success {

color: #4F8A10;
background-color: #DFF2BF;
background-image:url('images/success.png');
 }
 .warning {

color: #9F6000;
background-color: #FEEFB3;
background-image: url('images/warning.png');
 }
 .errormsgbox {

color: #D8000C;
background-color: #FFBABA;
background-image: url('images/error.png');

 }
 .validation {

color: #D63301;
background-color: #FFCCBA;
background-image: url('images/error.png');
 }



 </style>

  </head>
  <body>


  <form action="login.php" method="post" class="registration_form">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Login Form  </legend>

  <p>Enter Your username and Password Below  </p>

  <div class="elements">
  <label for="name">Email :</label>
  <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" size="25" />
  </div>

  <div class="elements">
  <label for="Password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" size="25" />
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  Go Back to <a href="#">Account Verification on sign up</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I'm not sure if I need to post the sql fields from the db.
I know the member page has this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
     header("Location: login.php");
}


?>
```

I don't know where the Username is coming from, nor do I have it in my db. I've tried changing it to a field I do have, but no luck.

Comment: wow, try posting only relevant code samples, not the whole file...

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: you should not overwrite the $_SESSION Global this way `$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array` you should loop through the sql result and specifically add your session key/values. also any code after the `header("Location: login.php");` will be executed you need to add die; after a header redirect

Comment: Do you really store passwords as plain text in your table? Unescaped `$password` variable is also a very nice injection vector.

Comment: I understand the risk of the plain passwords, however, the server that reads this specific information doesn't have md5 built into it. So, I'm limited to plain.
The error it gives, is login/password incorrect. If it was, I wouldn't have been able to register then authenticate it. Also, the member page is the one redirecting back to the login with the error. Only thing I could think is that the Username is incorrect session handler.

Comment: @knittl I'm still learning php. I haven't done oop cause I need to get the basic's down first. I've learned that just asking for help, usually helps me in the longer run. I agree that it's bad practice to have unhashed passwords, but there's more to the story.
A friend setup a perl script to parse info to/from the database to a auth.txt file. The background server reads the auth.txt in plain text only. So, to hash the password would cause more headache at this point than anything. Once I've gotten the hang of php, I'll ask about adjusting the perl to include a way to hash/unhash.
Thank you.

Comment: @MichalPlško I wasn't sure what part of it was relevant and having the whole thing present allows for a better rewrite. I might have missed something if I was selective. But I'll do better in the future.
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is happening that isn't right? "...pitches a fit..." is pretty generic, and doesn't really give us much information to help you.
Also, what is " AND code IS NULL; " supposed to do? Don't you want just the rows where the username and password match the given criterion?

Comment: @BBuchanan: this has nothing to do with OOP – I did not even mention OOP… And which PHP install does not have some sort of hashing library built in??

Comment: From what I can tell @Goldentoa11 the attempts to login, begins the redirect and session but the member page has a different session name to which I'm not sure where it was set. 
    And code is NULL; <- is checking if the account is active or not via the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: You should escape the mysql input.

```
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email ='$Email' AND cpassword='$Password') AND code IS NULL";
```

should be

```
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email =".mysqli_real_escape_string($Email)." AND cpassword=".mysqli_real_escape_string($Password).") AND code IS NULL";
```

Secondly, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't do

```
$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

But rather something like

```
$_SESSION['userdata'] = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

The $_SESSION['Username'] could be from some earlier code that did set it.

Comment: So, if I set the
    $_SESSION['userdata'] 
to a matching field in the db, it should work? or should I specific field?
To get to the user id, I have two other fields before it. Specifically:
  innittime, id, cid
where innittime is specifc to the background server, id is the persons hidden id updated per member, and cid is the specific id that they would need to login with.

Comment: the id would be in `$_SESSION['userdata']['id']` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a long shot, and it might take some fiddling around with to get it working, but maybe try changing

```
if (@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1)
//if Query is successfull A match was made.
{ 
  $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//Assign the result of this query to SESSION Global Variable
  header("Location: page.php");
}
```

to

```
if (@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1)
//if Query is successfull A match was made.
{ 
  session_register("userdata");
$_SESSION['userdata'] = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//Assign the result of this query to SESSION Global Variable
  header("Location: page.php");
}
```

and then, on the members page, try changing

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
   header("Location: login.php");
}
```

to

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['Username']) && !isset($_SESSION['userdata']) ){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```